# Feature request: question title should appear above question preview

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, titles, markdown-preview

Just a minor niggle - when I'm reviewing my question, one of the things I want to review is the title. It would be nice if the title appeared just above the preview of my question, so I could review my question all at once, without looking in two different places to see the question body and the title.

Comment: [meta.se]: [Please include the title in the question preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115247). [math.meta.se]: [Why not add the title of the question in the preview while writing it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25252) and [Latex preview on question title?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20248)

Comment: Seeing that the question linked in the previous comment is about titles in general and this is a problem mainly on the sites with MathJax, I have posted a new feature request on [meta.se]: [Show a preview of the title when editing/asking - at least on the MathJax sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361217)